# Работа с памятью в С#

Tags: c#

Примеры: [msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Метод Dispose вызывается для освобождения памяти (некий free c C), просто все объекты обладающие, которые хотят иметь метод Dispose должны наследоватся от
Здесь в примере "Реализация шаблона удаления для базового класса" возникает вопрос:
Как я понимаю метод public void Dispose() есть почти стандартным, а вот метод protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) меняется.

Интересует второй метод: ***зачем в нем второе условия, где комментарий Free any other managed objects here?*** Оно там не нужно, т.к предыдущее условия не даст пойти дальше, а если там вызвать метод Dispose (другого объекта), то он не даст пойти дальше по той же причине.

И вопрос о моем классе:

```
class YYY {
    ...
}

class JJJ {
   private YYY y;

   ...
   public void set(string name, int age)
   {
       if (y.nameValid(name)) //проверка правильности
          y.name = name;
       else
          return;
       if (y.ageValid(age))
          y.age = age;
       else
          return;
       // и т.д
   }

   public YYY get() {
       return y;
   }
}
```

Метод get возращает объект типа YYY, но он должен возвратить либо полностью заполненный объект, либо пустой. 
Как я понимаю, мне нужно его в этом случаи переписать как:

```
public void set(string name, int age)
       {
           if (y.nameValid(name))
           {
              y.name = name;
           }
           else 
           {
              y = null;
              return;
           }
           if (y.ageValid(age))
           {
              y.age = age;
           }
           else 
           {
              y = null;
              return;
           }

           // и т.д
       }
```

***То есть в случаи неудачи просто присвоить null, а замет когда-то он удалится?***
Сам класс YYY - это класс контейнер с несколькими методами.

***Я не могу понять, когда нужен Dispose, а когда нет?*** С методом Close все ясно.
Вот в этом случаи он нужен? Мне кажется, что в классе YYY он не нужен, потому что это класс контейнер.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Начну с того, что, судя по постановке вопроса, у вас в голове каша относительно смысла и реализации dispose-паттерна. Начнем по порядку:

> зачем в нем второе условия, где комментарий Free any other managed objects here? Оно там не нужно

Специалисты Microsoft, конечно, менее авторитетные специалисты в сравнении с вами, однако же они скромно полагают, что смысл в этом есть - два условия, о которых вы говорите, **не являются одинаковыми**:

```
 if (disposed)
     return; 

 if (disposing) {
     // Free any other managed objects here

  }
```

В первом из них проверяется, освобождены ли уже ресурсы, а второе условие проверяет, откуда именно вызывается метод **Dispose(bool disposing)** - из метода **Dispose** или из финализатора. Как можно видеть, это два очень разных условия, а потому они не перекрывают друг друга

> С методом Close все ясно

если у вас нет ясности с методом Dispose, то и с Close все ясно также быть не может, поскольку Close - это по сути то же самый Dispose (более подробно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524903/should-i-call-close-or-dispose-for-stream-objects))

> То есть в случаи неудачи просто присвоить null, а замет когда-то он удалится?

для корректной очистки ресурсов никакого присваивания null не нужно - в C# есть сборщик мусора, бережно хранящий вас от множества попыток прострелить себе ногу

> Я не могу понять, когда нужен Dispose, а когда нет?

И наконец шокирующая правда: **В том коде, что вы привели, никакой Dispose-паттерн не нужен**. Однако не нужен он не "потому что это класс контейнер", а потому что там просто нечего освобождать - ваши классы не содержат ни управляемых, ни тем более неуправляемых ресурсов . Во всяком случае в том виде, в котором они тут приведены (и еще, стоит отметить, они очень плохо написаны).

Так вот - когда же нужен Dispose? Реализация Dispose-паттерна необходима в двух случаях - если класс содержит неуправляемые ресурсы (это всяческие дескрипторы файлов, окон, указатели и прочие  ужасные слова из мира С++), либо управляемые ресурсы (те, что сами реализуют IDisposable). Помимо приведенной выше статьи об это можно почитать также [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/89720/) и [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129283/)

З.Ы. Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать чуть более грамотно - это, конечно, не урок русского языка и словесности, однако же порой ваши мысли очень сложно понять, настолько бессвязно они выражены

Comment: Вот ещё несколько эффективных методов использования `IDisposable`, не связанных прямо или косвенно с неуправляемыми ресурсами, в стиле RAII: http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/03_LifetimeManagement.html#IDisposable

Comment: И [вот ещё](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10316418/276994).

Comment: в каких случаях тогда нужен деструктор? Что в нем писать, если сборщик мусора или мы все равно вызовем метод dispose.

Comment: @andreyk: Деструктор нужен в случае, если вы хотите таки подчистить ресурсы в случае, если глупый пользователь по невнимательности (или в результате ошибки) не вызвал `Dispose`. Управляемые ресурсы в этом случае подчистить не удастся (но их всё равно съест сборка мусора), а вот неуправляемые — можно. Этим-то и занимается деструктор.

Comment: @andreyk разберитесь с dispose-паттерном, тогда все встанет на свои места. Прочитайте повнимательнее вышеуказанные статьи, там есть ответы на все ваши вопросы. Кстати, в С# нет деструкторов, в нем есть финализаторы.

Comment: @VladD Управляемые - это те, которые наследуются от IDisposable, а неуправляемые - все остальные. Есть массив неуправляемый ресурсов типа string. В Си++ я бы в деструкторе вызвал ему delete, а в Шапре такого нету. Присвоить null также нет особого смысла.

Comment: дополнения к Dispose https://ideone.com/mVs1x3

Comment: > Есть массив неуправляемый ресурсов типа string

@andreyk вы почему-то очень невнимательно читаете. **string** не является  неуправляемым ресурсом. Его **не нужно** очищать. Неуправляемые ресурсы - это ресурсы, получаемые из неуправляемого кода - указатели, дескрипторы и прочее. Для всего остального есть сборщик мусора, он сделает за вас львиную долю работы

Comment: @andreyk: Неуправляемые ресурсы — это ресурсы, не являющиеся .NET-объектами. Ресурсы типа `string` очевидно являются управляемыми. А вот указатель на блок памяти, полученный при помощи `GlobalAlloc` — это нативный ресурс.

(Уточнение: и правда, в C# не деструкторы, а финализаторы, я выразился неточно.)